# Uninstalling App with Start-Process Fails

Tags: powershell, windows-10, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall an application using the Start-Process cmdlet. I am able to have the uninstaller prompt, but after selecting "Continue" the app is not removed. When I try to run the same Script while signed in as the user I am able to uninstall it. We use remote software that allows us to run commands in the background if that helps. Please take a look at the code used.

```
[cmdletbinding()]

Param (

    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$thisUser
    
    )
    


<#$thisUser = $env:UserName#>
$isItClosed = Get-Process -n "theApp2Uninstall"
Stop-Process -InputObject $isItClosed -Force 

$CCAppPath = "C:\Users\$($thisUser)\AppData\Local\Programs\theApp2Uninstall" 

if(test-path -path $CCAppPath){
start-process "C:\Users\$($thisUser)\AppData\Local\Programs\theApp2Close\Uninstall theApp2Uninstall.exe" 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case was resolved!! Turns out that the Company that developed the app just did a really bad job. This Script works well when uninstalling other apps... so please feel free to use it.

Thanks to those that gave it a shot.